# Antivirus Scaning Exclusion

Tags: anti-virus

I am writing to ask you if anyone knows any way to ecxlude an .exe file from antivirus scanning when it executes.

I would like to give the user the opportunity to exclude my app from the antivirus list during the installation, so the antivirus never check the application when it executes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How this is accomplished depends on the specific AV being used.  It also depends on if the user has the necessary permissions to do so.

Answer (score 2):

If a program could mark *itself* as excluded, that would be awfully convenient for malware, wouldn't it.

Most antivirus software do have exclusion lists. However, the location of these lists is different for every antivirus program. (Remember, there isn't just "*the* antivirus software", there's well over 30 competing antivirus products out there – and of  course they all work differently. The only thing they were forced to agree on is reporting to Windows whether the protection is active or not.)

And for many antivirus products, these lists and other settings can only be updated through its own control panel, not externally – this is part of their self-defense against malware. (Stopping the antivirus services, changing their registry settings, etc. is an ages old trick.)

So in short, there is no *generic* or automated method for you to do this. It's something the user would have to configure by themselves.

If your software is misdetected as malware, instead start by contacting the antivirus vendors about why this happens (false positives are not a new thing at all). Sites such as VirusTotal can help with checking the program against multiple antivirus systems before it's released.

On the other hand, if your software is legitimately detected as malware,